# What is BlackList and why it is used in Tether Token Smart Contract? And what is the use of Pause and Unpause in Tether?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain, tokens

contract BlackList is Ownable, BasicToken {

```
function getBlackListStatus(address _maker) external constant returns (bool) {
    return isBlackListed[_maker];
}
function getOwner() external constant returns (address) {
    return owner;
}
mapping (address => bool) public isBlackListed;
function addBlackList (address _evilUser) public onlyOwner {
    isBlackListed[_evilUser] = true;
    emit AddedBlackList(_evilUser); //event emmiting
}
function removeBlackList (address _clearedUser) public onlyOwner {
    isBlackListed[_clearedUser] = false;
    emit RemovedBlackList(_clearedUser);
}
function destroyBlackFunds (address _blackListedUser) public onlyOwner {
    require(isBlackListed[_blackListedUser]);
    uint dirtyFunds = balanceOf(_blackListedUser);
    balances[_blackListedUser] = 0;
    _totalSupply -= dirtyFunds;
    emit DestroyedBlackFunds(_blackListedUser, dirtyFunds);
}
event DestroyedBlackFunds(address _blackListedUser, uint _balance);
event AddedBlackList(address _user);
event RemovedBlackList(address _user);
```

}

contract Pausable is Ownable {

```
event Pause();
event Unpause();
bool public paused = false;
modifier whenNotPaused() {
require(!paused);
_;
```

}
  modifier whenPaused() {
    require(paused);
    _;
}

function pause() onlyOwner whenNotPaused public {
    paused = true;
    emit Pause();
  }
 function unpause() onlyOwner whenPaused public {
    paused = false;
    emit Unpause();
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of BlackLiast is to provide functionality to block users to prevent unusual activities over contract. For pause or unpause i can't see any function regarding in your given code please provide full code so it can get easy to answer.

Comment: contract Pausable is Ownable {
  event Pause();
  event Unpause();

  bool public paused = false;

  modifier whenNotPaused() {
    require(!paused);
    _;
  }
  modifier whenPaused() {
    require(paused);
    _;
  }
  function pause() onlyOwner whenNotPaused public {
    paused = true;
    emit Pause();
  }

  function unpause() onlyOwner whenPaused public {
    paused = false;
    emit Unpause();
  }
}

Comment: yes, just mailed ... on your mailid given in your profile.